# "Composer Update" error after gd install in ubuntu vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, gd, composer-php, php-gd

Hi i have the following dependency in my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "gd": ">=2.0.28",
    "ext-gd": "*"
}
```

when i do composer update it gives the following error...

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- The requested package gd could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
Potential causes:
    - A typo in the package name
    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.**
```

however i have install php-gd using command : **sudo apt-get install php5-gd**

is there any thing else to do to get this working??

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"gd" is no known PHP library package name. If you want to enforce having an extension present, you have to use "ext-gd" only.

Note that Composer recommends not to enforce versions on extensions because their version schema might be inconsistent. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#platform-packages

Answer (score 0):

you can try

> $ composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.1"